# Weird Python Cron Job Issue

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, cron

I am running Python 3.7 on Ubuntu Server 16.04, and I have a really basic Python script that runs fine from the command line, and it runs fine via a simple shell script, and when I setup a cron job via crontab -e, or webmin, cron jobs will appear in the logs as having happened. However, the script doesn't actually run, as I have it set to log itself, and it logs nothing. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

my shell script (getprice.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
python3.7 /home/websites/www.coin-stack.com/py/getprice.py
```

my python code (getprice.py):

```
#!/usr/bin python3.7
import requests
import json
import logging
# ******************************* Settings *****************************************************************************
# Logging Setup
debug_level = 'INFO'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='run.log', format=' %(asctime)s -  %(levelname)s -  %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
crawl_queue = []
delay = 60
url = 'http://www.somedomainoranother.com/?p=somepage'
# **********************************************************************************************************************
def main():
    data = get_prices(url)
    data = json.loads(data)
    # Bitcoin
    btc = data['BTC']
    btc = btc['USD']
    return btc

def get_prices(url):
    resp = requests.get(url=url)
    data = resp.content
    return data
main()
```

my cron job:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/websites/www.mydomain.com/py/getprice.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me on my production server as well!
Please try the following in crontab.

```
*/10 * * * * /home/websites/www.mydomain.com/py/getprice.sh > /path/cronjob.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Okay, that helps a lot, now the new log file tells me that python3.7 isn't found, but it is found when I run the shell script directly, so why is cron confused on the path? Is there a way to make it more explicit?

Comment: I think you should remove the python3.7 from the shell script and change the crontab note to
*/10 * * * * python3.7 /home/websites/www.mydomain.com/py/getprice.sh > /path/cronjob.log 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

The solution, after I was advised to add the extra crontab info to get useful data out of the log file, was to utilize the full path to the exact python executable needed instead of letting cron use whatever python it likes most, which I am guessing is the default 2.7 on Ubuntu server. So if you want to force cron to use Python 3.7, use the full path:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /home/scripts/py/getprice.py
```